# Is this about identifing an interactive online IDE a question for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm not sure but, does this sound like a question for Stack Overflow community?

[Where can I interactively play with jQuery and Javascript?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/where-can-i-interactively-play-with-jquery-and-javascript) [closed]

Comment: I think you should specify why /you/ think it should go somewhere else if you're posting the objection. Rather, than raising an objection and allowing others to infer what /you/ believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it could go either way.  I would be happy to see it on Stack Overflow, but I also think that it fits here, as OP is asking about a web app version of a development environment, which is what the site is all about.

Answer (score 5):

I think it is fine here, and if asked on SO fine there as well. Here, the question is not asking about writing specific JavaScript, but an app that allows you to run the code and interact with it. That distinction is what makes it ok for me.

Comment: There must me many questions having similar case throughout stackexchange sites. How about having some way that this question can be linked from stackoverflow also so that stackoverflow community people can also reply on this. Now, I'm not just talking about this question.

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023, this kind of questions will be closed as

> Questions asking for us to **recommend or find a Web Application** are off-topic and out of scope, as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. However, your question may be on topic at [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) if you can rewrite it so that it meets their [quality guidelines](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).